# What can we say about the definite integral and Riemann sums?

Tags: analysis

Consider $$f(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}$$ and $$g(x) = \sum_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}.$$

I would like to say that $f(x) < g(x)$ for all natural numbers $x \ge 1$.

Is there an easy way to derive this from Riemann sums? I see $g(x)$ as an "over-estimate" of $f(x)$ in terms of Riemann sums. But I don't really know enough about Riemann sums to state this formally. Can someone help with the formalism aspect?

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty obvieous that $1/x < 1/t \forall x \in [t,t+1]$ Now you can just say

$$f(x) = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} = \int_1^2 \frac{dt}{t} + \int_2^3 \frac{dt}{t} + \ldots + \int_{x-1}^x \frac{dt}{t}$$

$$\leq \frac 1 1 + \frac 1 2 + \ldots + \frac{1}{x-1}  = g(x)-\frac 1 x \leq g(x)$$